# AP Computer Science Principles and Unity

Tags: ap-cs-principles, game-design

I have taught AP Computer Science A for years, but I have not taught AP Computer Science Principles as of yet.  My understanding of the course is that it's quite flexible on terms of languages taught.

I've been noodling around with creating a course in game design using Unity, and I wondered how much that could be merged into APCSP.  Has anyone taught APCSP using Unity for a substantial portion of the course, and how did that go?  Alternatively, is this really not possible under the AP curriculum?

Comment: A better place to ask this is on the APCS mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a ["Create with Code" curriculum](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/08/14/create-with-code-learn-teach-computer-programming-by-making-games/) that is aligned to ISTE standards:

> Most importantly, Create with Code is designed to work in the classroom. Aligned to ISTE Standards for computer science education, educators can leverage the free course curriculum to support instruction inside and outside of class. Flexible teaching materials are provided in addition to the learner-facing instructional videos...

The above site has an ISTE standards alignment document, as well as a scope and sequence, set of lesson plans, and a course syllabus. Many of the ISTE standards map pretty well to to [AP CSP standards.](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/pdf/ap-computer-science-principles-course-and-exam-description.pdf)

AP CSP is pretty flexible in terms of which set of tools you use, so I think you'd be safe with Unity:

[image: screenshot of tools listed in linked document]